# What is the Java pattern to return functions with different signatures based on some condition?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm trying to write a `Client` class which can look up entities from an external data store. The main parameter used to look up entities is a key. The problem is that sometimes a key is just a `userId`, sometimes it's a combination of `userId` and `productId`. So I'd like to enforce the consumer of my `Client` API to use a key builder specific to an entity. I tried the code below:

```java
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Client {
  public Function getBuilder(SomeEnum type) {
    switch (type) {
      case TYPE_X:
        BiFunction<String, String, Entity> builder = (userId, productId) -> {
          String key = userId + "-" + productId;
          // lookup something in external data store based on the key and return the found entity
        };
        return builder;
      case TYPE_Y:
        Function<String, Entity> b = appId -> {
          String key = userId;
          // lookup something in external data store based on the key and return the found entity
        };
        return b;
    }
  }
}
```

The code doesn't compile of course because the return types don't match. I'm wondering if the code can be fixed and if not what is the correct Java pattern to enforce such builders with different signatures.

Comment: Note: not using a generic type on your return type is a raw type, something you absolutely never do. And yeah: just not possible: you can't have different return types from the same method in Java, unless returning Object for example.

Comment: Where would such a function-that-returns-functions-with-different-parameter-counts be useful? In the above case, I argue (see answer below) that using an interface would be much clearer. You *could* just return a `Function` that takes a `String[]` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `KeyBuilder` interface as follows, and implement it differently for each type. No enums needed:

```
 public interface KeyBuilder {
     String buildKey();
 }

 // things that use userId & productId:
 public class Foo implements KeyBuilder {
     // ...
     public String buildKey() { return userId + "-" + productId; }
 }

 // things that use appId {
 public class Bar implements KeyBuilder {
     // ...
     public String buildKey() { return appId; }
 }
```

Then, your code becomes cleaner and is still easy to test

```
 // before: have to build explicitly 
 lookupSomethingExternal(foo.getUserId() + "-" + foo.getProductId());
 lookupSomethingExternal(bar.getAppId());

 // after: lookupSomethingInternal expects something implementing KeyBuilder
 lookupSomethingExternal(foo);
 lookupSomethingExternal(bar);

 // after: can mock for unit-tests
 lookupSomethingExternal(() -> "testKey");
```

Comment: The issue with the answer is that it requires the caller of `lookupSomethingExternal` to instantiate key builder class (there may be more logic than key building) which is why I wanted to concentrate all such logic in `Client` class. And I wanted `getBuilder` to return something generic that would require the caller to supply required parameters.

Comment: `lookupSomethingExternal` does not need to instantiate anything - it takes anything that implements `KeyBuilder` as a parameter. That anything may or may not have additional logic - `lookupSomethingExternal` does not care, as long as it implements `KeyBuilder`. Why are you convinced that you need a factory?